# Text views within a frame in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I am building a simple app and I want to provide a ‘frame’ within 2 textviews, as shown below:

[image]

I have tried (and not very successfully!) using RelativeLayout, TableLayout, etc.
What would be easiest way please and a simple example would be absolutely brilliant if possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation to achieve that kind of `layout` along with shape `drawable` as `background` something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/frame_border"
    tools:src="@drawable/default_avatar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="TextView 1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30 cm" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and for `background`, use below `frame_border.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:color="#000" android:width="4dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that! When I use the XML the LinearLayout looks fine but the TextViews are not visible? It looks fine in Android Studio but when I run the code it’s empty? Any help please? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have updated code, converted `text` from `tools` to `android`, copy this new code it will work

Comment: That is brilliant! Really appreciate the help, Cheers